# Clicking a sub category should only show the sub items of that category

Tags: jquery

When I click the main category it shows me sub categories. After clicking a sub category it opens all the sub items inside the sub category. For all the given sub categories in that particular main category, if I just click on 1 sub category it should only show the sub items of 1 category.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.main-category").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div.sub-category").toggle();
  });

  $("a.show-item").click(function() {
    $("ul.show-subitem").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-subitem {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.margin-15px {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

a.full-width {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <a class="main-category full-width">SSC</a>
    <div class="sub-category hide-subitem">
      <ul class="exam-type">
        <li><a class="show-item full-width">SSC CGL</a></li>
        <ul class="show-subitem margin-15px">
          <li>2019</li>
          <li>2018</li>
          <li>2017</li>
          <li>2016</li>
          <li>2015</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="exam-type">
          <li><a class="show-item full-width">SSC CGL</a></li>
          <ul class="show-subitem margin-15px">
            <li>2019</li>
            <li>2018</li>
            <li>2017</li>
            <li>2016</li>
            <li>2015</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: You need to use DOM traversal to fix this. However we can't give you a specific solution without also seeing the related HTML/CSS

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under the question to add more details

Comment: Already added request you to please provide solution as soon as possible thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways. However, the easiest would be the one you already implemented by placing the **trigger** and **target** at the same level of tree and just toggling the element next to the trigger using `next()`

> Edit: As now you have provided your own HTML code which has some
>   differences with the one I assumed before. So you have to call
>   `parentsUntil()` before calling `next()` to get the job done.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a.main-category").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div.sub-category").toggle();
  });

  $("a.show-item").click(function() {
    $(this).parentsUntil("ul").next("ul.show-subitem").toggle();
  });

});
```

Also, you need to add this to your **CSS** as well:

```
.show-subitem {
  display: none;
}
```